How to tell if a matrix is 1-D or 2-D or... how to know if len(lst) is the number of rows of a 2-D matrix or the number of cols of a 1-D matrix?
I am learning python and puzzled by this error while trying to tell if a matrix is 1-D or 2-D. (they are all integers and rectangular since I am multiplying them. That is why I call them matrices)
I am trying to find the dimensions of the matrices so that I can create a new matrix representing their product. (m,n) x (n,p) = (m,p)
How to know if len(lst) is the number of rows of a 2-D matrix or the number of cols of a 1-D matrix?
Approach 1
def matrix_multiplication(H, lst):
    # your code here
    print(f'H {H}')
    print(f'lst {lst}')

    rA = len(H)
    cA = len(H[0]) if rA > 0 else 0
    rB = len(lst)
    cB = len(lst[0]) if rB > 0 else 0
    print(f'H: {rA}x{cA}')
    print(f'lst: {rB}x{cB}')
    return (H)

A1 = [[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1]]
b1 = [1,1,1,0]
c1 = matrix_multiplication(A1, b1)
print('c1=', c1)
assert c1 == [1,1,0] , 'Test 1 failed'

--------OUTPUT----------
  H [[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]] lst [1, 1, 1, 0] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Me\Documents\Learn\MS-CS\Foundations of Data Structures and Algorithms\assignment_week3.py", line 42, in <module>
        c1 = matrix_multiplication(A1, b1)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\Me\Documents\Learn\MS-CS\Foundations of Data Structures and Algorithms\assignment_week3.py", line 20, in matrix_multiplication
        cB = len(lst[0]) if rB > 0 else 0
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
    ------------------------


Why are you importing numpy to NOT use it?

shape is an attribute of numpy.ndarray, it won't work on lists

What are your functions even trying to do? [ask]

@folengateis I removed approach 2

@Julien I am trying to find the dimensions of the matrices so that I can create a new matrix representing their product

What's unclear about your error? [ask]

@Julien how to know if len(lst) is the number of rows of a 2-D matrix or the number of cols of a 1-D matrix.

@likejudo, lists aren't matrices and there's no such thing as a "2-D list". Do you really want to know if all elements in a list are themselves lists? Do the inner lists need to all contain integers, or can they contain other things (lists, floating-point numbers, strings...)? Do all inner lists need to be the same length (making the nested data structure "rectangular")?

@Chris yes, they are all integers and rectangular since I am multiplying them. That is why I called them matrices.

You were importing numpy at some point, why aren't you using it rather than reinventing a square wheel?

you should test the type of the sublist
def test_shape(list_):
    if isinstance(list_[0], list):
        print('list_ is 2d')
    else:
        print('list_ is 1d')


An empty list is still a list. Pass an empty list to your function and see what happens. type(list_[0]) is list may not give you the result you expect if list_[0] is a subclass of list. isinstance() is preferred.

For this particular case where you want to determine if a list has one or two dimensions then:
def dimensions(x: list) -> int:
    return 2 if x and isinstance(x[0], list) else 1

A1 = [[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1]]
b1 = [1,1,1,0]

print(dimensions(A1))
print(dimensions(b1))

Output:
2
1

Note:
This will not work for lists with more than 2 dimensions.
Also, be aware that an empty list is still a list with 1 dimension

thank you. I don't know why I did not find this function before dimensions
